# Vertically align characters raised with \stackrel

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, stacking-symbols

I learned from [Stefan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz)'s reply to [Putting a character above another character](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3446) to use `\stackrel` in math mode to do just that. I'm using that right now to mark segments of a word as having a high (H) or low (L) tone. In some words, however, the characters that I put H or L above are of different heights. How can I align the raised characters H and L vertically?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
h$\stackrel{\text{L}}{\text{a}}$nd$\stackrel{\text{H}}{\text{l}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**:
The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35013/9077) to [Adjusting vertical and horizonal spacing in \stackrel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35012/adjusting-vertical-and-horizonal-spacing-in-stackrel) suggests (like Barbara below) to use `\strut` for each element. When using double spacing, however, this raises the characters way too high.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,setspace}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
h$\stackrel{\text{L}}{\strut{\text{a}}}$nd$\stackrel{\text{H}}{\strut{\text{l}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can add `\strut` to the lower element to ensure that it will always be full height.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I tried that now, and it raises the L even higher than the H. I could, of course, add ``\strut`` to both, but I'd prefer to not raise the characters more than necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `\strut` to make them vertically aligned. Or add a `\vphantom` only when necessary.

This is a relatively low-level implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

% cf. \oalign and \mathstrut in LaTeX kernel
\newcommand\textoverset[3][(]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \baselineskip0pt \lineskip.25ex
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\crcr
      \scriptsize#2\cr
      \vphantom{#1}#3\crcr}}}

\linespread{3}

\begin{document}

h\textoverset{L}{a}nd\textoverset{H}{l}

h\textoverset[l]{L}{a}nd\textoverset[]{H}{l}% add a template manually

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second example prevents the raised characters from being raised too high when ``\doublespacing`` is used, but what is the reason that the H is lower in the second example than in the first example (and in my original example)?

Comment: @Sverre: See my update.

Comment: @Sverre: `\strut` may be very high if you set `\doublespacing`. You can use other struts you like.

Comment: I'd avoid `\strut` for this. Better using the height of a letter with ascenders as `\vphantom`.

Comment: I can't follow this discussion now. And I don't understand why Leo's two examples have different heights for the raised characters. Could someone dumb this down a bit for me (I'm also curious what your suggestion entails, egreg)?

Comment: @egreg: So I use `(` now.

Comment: @Sverre: My macro sets `\vphantom` with the optional argument if exist, or use `\vphantom{(}`. The second example use the letter `l` for `\vphantom`, which is a little lower than symbol `(`.

Comment: How can I simplify your command if I don't need to use the ``\vphantom`` option? In practice, I just created two different commands: One for adding H and L above x-height characters characters (like a, e, o, u, n), and one for l-height characters (so far only l). I.e. I no longer need the ability to add a custom character when needed.